# Scala - avoid override of a super class field in the copy method

Tags: scala, inheritance, functional-programming, overwrite, case-class

Let's say for instance that I have the following classes, is there a way to do the copy command without overriding the argument from the superclass?

I want to avoid `override val arg1: String` from the declaration of - `case class MyCaseClass(override val arg1: String, arg2: String) extends MyAbstractClass`

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass (val arg1: String = "bar 1")

case class MyCaseClass(arg2: String) extends MyAbstractClass

object MyMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val myObj = MyCaseClass(arg2 = "bar 2")
    println("a.arg1: " + myObj.arg1) // a.arg1: bar 1
    println("a.arg2: " + myObj.arg2) // a.arg2: bar 2

   val b = myObj.copy(arg1 = "try_1", arg2 = "try_2") 

//>> "too many arguments (2) for method copy: (arg2: String)com.MyCaseClass
//>> Note that 'arg1' is not a parameter name of the invoked method."
   
  }
}
```

Edit:
In my actual code I got hundreds of fields, that's why it's so important, I want to keep clean code and avoid hundreds of meaningless redundant overrides.

Comment: Nop, they don’t suggest a way to avoid the redundant ‘override val arg’. Thanks.

Comment: Why not `override val` or something similar? In this snippet you are turning the `arg1` into a constant from `MyCaseClass` user point of view. It's no longer a parameter and cannot be set from the outside.

Comment: Well, you could implement your own `copy` which would create an anonymous subtype of case class (`new MyCaseClass(arg2 = _arg2) { override val arg1 = _arg1})`), but why even putting this `val arg2` in your copy if it won't be a part of: apply/unapply/toString/equals/hashcode?

Comment: `arg1` is an immutable `val`. The only way to change the value would be by overriding it.

Comment: On my actual code I got hundreds of fields, that's why it's so important to keep clean code and avoid hundreds of meaningless overrides.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok you are probably right.

Comment: Your code is hardly clean if you: 1) assign a field a value in a supertype 2) override it making the first definition completely redundant 3) but forcing yourself to add `override val`. `val` is immutable so (in objects) it's assigned once, in a constructor. If you want to modify it through copy, and define it in a case class, then the first assignment can be removed. Then `override val` is not needed, compiler/linter/IDE might emit a warning (encouraging adding it) but even without `override val` it's a legal code, because you implemented an interface, not modified behavior of a superclass.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to NOT provide a value to `arg1`

```
trait MyAbstractClass {
  val arg1: String // no value assigned...
}

case class MyCaseClass(
  arg1: String = "bar 1", // ...no need for override val
  arg2: String
) extends MyAbstractClass
```

Then

```
val myObj = MyCaseClass(arg2 = "bar 2")
println("a.arg1: " + myObj.arg1) // a.arg1: bar 1
println("a.arg2: " + myObj.arg2) // a.arg2: bar 2

val b = myObj.copy(arg1 = "try_1", arg2 = "try_2")
```

works without any issue. The only difference is that default value would have to be provided for `arg1` in `MyCaseClass` constructor.

If you don't want to make `arg1` a part of:

- `MyCaseClass.apply`
- `MyCaseClass.unapply`
- `myCaseClass.toString`
- `myCaseClass.equals(anotherObject)`
- `myCaseClass.hashcode`

then probably using a `case class` is a bad idea in the first place, since `case class` is less of a "universal boilerplate generator" and more like a build-in way of defining records with a strong opinion what a record is. And there are alternatives to it like e.g. [contraband](https://www.scala-sbt.org/contraband/code-generation.html) with different opinions and decisions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mateusz Kubuszok suggested, that's might be the only option, which obviously doesn't make the code cleaner.

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass (val arg1: String = "bar 1")

case class MyCaseClass(val arg2: String) extends MyAbstractClass {

  def copy(newArg1: String, newArg2: String): MyCaseClass =
    new MyCaseClass(arg2 = newArg2) {
      override val arg1: String = newArg1
    }

}

object MyMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val myObj = MyCaseClass(arg2 = "bar 2")
    println("myObj.arg1: " + myObj.arg1) // myObj.arg1: bar 1
    println("myObj.arg2: " + myObj.arg2) // myObj.arg2: bar 2

   val mySecObj = myObj.copy(newArg1 = "try_1", newArg2 = "try_2")
    println("mySecObj.arg1: " + mySecObj.arg1) // mySecObj.arg1: try_1
    println("mySecObj.arg2: " + mySecObj.arg2) // mySecObj.arg2: try_2

  }
}
```